# Integrating exponential function with elliptic bounds

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I am trying to integrate the following:

$$\iint_R\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{16}\right)\:\mathrm{d}A$$

With the region $R$ having the bounds:

$$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{16}=3$$
$$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{16}=5$$

And I am completely stuck with where to begin on this. I am aware that it involves polar coordinates but even when attempting that it seems to get unbelievably messy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154206/set-up-double-integral-of-ellipse-in-polar-coordinates)

Comment: Looks like you've already asked this question before but with different numbers. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try elliptical coordinates instead, that is:
$$x = 2r \cos \theta $$
$$y = 4r \sin \theta $$

Then

$$ \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{16} = r^2 $$

and

$$ \frac{\partial (x, y)}{\partial (r, \theta)} = 8r $$

The integral becomes

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{5}} e^{r^2} 8r \,dr \,d\theta  $$

Answer (score 0):

First do a change of variables $y = 2 u$.  Then express $(x,u)$  in polar coordinates.

Comment: Can you explain where this comes from?

Comment: $x^2/4 + y^2/4$ is much nicer from the point of view of polar coordinates than $x^2/4 + y^2/16$.

Comment: Right but then how does this proceed from there? Now that you've changed it into a circle what do you do? There must be more to this.